# PQRS is a rectangle with PQ = 4cm and QR = 8 cm. ABCD is a rectangle such that P, Q, R and S lie on AB,BC, CD and DA respectively.

Tags: geometry

Then the maximum possible area of ABCD is?

I tried to attempt this question using A.M and G.M relationship. But the answer that I got is different from the actual answer.

Actual answer = 64 sq. cm

Answer that I obtained through A.M & G.M relationship = 72 sq. cm

Comment: Please show your attempts.

Comment: I'm not sure how I can show the diagram here. But, we basically find the are of 2 smaller right triangles and 2 bigger right triangles left in the rectangle ABCD after taking out rectangle PQRS. For the smaller triangles, area would be 0.5*base(x)*height(y). So here we try to maximise x*y. It's a right triangle with hypotenuse as 4. We know that, (x+y)/2 >= sq.root(xy) [Arithmetic Mean>=Geometric Mean]. From this I got 8>=x*y. I don't know how to use LaTeX here, so please bear.

Comment: To use latex put it into dollar sign parentheses. Your result is correct. Take $A(0,0)$, $B(6\sqrt{2},0)$, $C(6\sqrt{2},6\sqrt{2})$, $P(2\sqrt{2},0)$ and you'll see this.

Comment: So the answer (64 sq. cm) given by the book is incorrect?

Comment: Please include your attempts as an edit to your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[image]

$PQ=4$ and $QR=8$

$\triangle BPQ \sim \triangle CQR$

Let $BP=x$ and $BQ=y$ then $CQ=2x$ and $CR=2y$

$x^2+y^2=16$

$\text{Area ABCD}=(x+2y)\times (2x+y)= 2x^2+2y^2+5xy\leq 2\times 16 + 5\times 8=72$

$16=x^2+y^2\geq 2xy$

$xy\leq 8$

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: @DarEul : You are welcome.

Comment: "please show your attempts" (you).  No attempts shown.  You answer anyway.  Please review quality standards, e.g., [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), and then, as an answerer, please review [Enforcement of quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?r=SearchResults&s=2|140.5115), to which all answerers are responsible.

Comment: @amWhy :  his attempts are in the comments

Comment: @"Lion Heart"  Okay, but you should have posted, in the comments to the asker:  "Please include your attempts as an edit to your question."  Like I Just did.  Context in comments belongs as edits in posts.

Comment: Now, consider yourself served with the Enforcement of Quality Standards.  Subsequently, it will be appropriate to flag your answers to poor questions you've done nothing to assist the asker to improve.